# Different versions of make

Tags: windows, gcc, makefile

I have written a small makefile to build a little projects. I'm running make 3.82.90. this make-version is coming with the mingw installation. 
I have a second pc, which is unable to run the makefile. The make version is 5.2. I don't know this version, it seems to come frome another programm. Mingw is even installed on this pc.

Does anyone knows where this make comes from?
Maybe I must change a environment variable, that the mingw make is found first. Know somebody which one?

Comment: Did you try `make -v`?

Comment: Shure. Because of that I know that I have different versions. I don`t know how to execute the "right" make and where make 5.2 comes from (not from mingw)

Comment: What's the full output of `make -v`?

Comment: What kind of make are you using (nmake, gmake, ...)?

Comment: C:\Users\hr>make -v
MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987,
Incorrect command line argument: -v

and the working one

C:\Users\mri>make -v
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: Could be the Borland version of make

Comment: Usually the version bundled with MinGW is called `mingw32-make.exe` and not `make.exe`. Try running this instead.

Comment: @ user657267: You are right!
@Chnossos: I will try it

Answer (score 0):

The different make is from borland. Call of mingw-32 solved the problem.